# How to execute this java double scanner?

Tags: java, input

When calling scanDouble(); I get an error.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void printLogarithm(double x){
    if(x <= 0.0){
        System.err.println("Error: x must be positive.");
        return;
    }
    double result=Math.log(x);
    System.out.println("The log of x is"+ result);
}
public static void scanDouble(Scanner in) {
    System.out.print("Enter the name: ");
    if (!in.hasNextDouble()){
        String word = in.next();
        System.err.println(word + "is not a number");
        return;
    }
    double x = in.nextDouble();
    printLogarithm(x);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
scanDouble();
}
}
```

Does anyone know how to execute scanDouble(); Is there something I should include in the method call?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: im tried to execute object ScanDouble() because now i can't put nothing in consola input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow your logic, try passing the Scanner variable `in` inside the `scanDouble()` method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);   
    scanDouble(in);
}
```

Passing a double value `x` for instance as an argument won't work, I just tested it.

Comment: if i put scanDouble(in) i get error Error:(31, 20) java: non-static variable in cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: i forgot about  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); thanks dude